# Attempting to use python-sounddevice lower level "stream" classes to play and record with NumPy arrays giving errors

Tags: python, numpy, python-sounddevice, soundfile

I'm trying to split the audio file into a given number of NumPy blocks and put those into RAM to play, just like [play_a_very_long_sound_file](https://python-sounddevice.readthedocs.io/en/0.3.15/examples.html#play-a-very-long-sound-file). Unfortunately, I believe my knowledge of NumPy arrays and audio files in general is lacking. Once this code is working, I'd like to add a recording process in the callback function. With the code I currently have, I'm getting:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: ''
```

which is taking place in the second `if` block within the callback function. I'm trying to add zeros to the end of the `outdata` block, but am unsure of how to go about it.

Another curious thing is that I'm only getting a numpy array returned from `soundfile.read()`, which normally returns a numpy array and a samplerate. But I'm assuming this is caused by me breaking it up into frames.

```
def callback(outdata, frames, time, status):
  assert frames == args.blocksize
  if status.output_underflow:
    print('Output underflow: increase blocksize?', file=sys.stderr)
    raise sd.CallbackAbort
  assert not status
  try:
    data = q.get_nowait()
  except queue.Empty:
    print('Buffer is empty: increase buffersize?', file=sys.stderr)
    raise sd.CallbackAbort
  if len(data) < len(outdata):
    outdata[:len(data),0] = data
    outdata[len(data):,0] = b'\x00' * (len(outdata) - len(data))
    raise sd.CallbackStop
  else:
    outdata[:,0] = data

try:
  with sf.SoundFile(args.filename) as f:
    for _ in range(args.buffersize):
        data = f.read(frames=args.blocksize, dtype='float32')
        if data.size == 0:
            break
        q.put_nowait(data)  # Pre-fill queue
    stream = sd.OutputStream(  
        samplerate=f.samplerate, blocksize=args.blocksize,
        device=args.device, channels=f.channels, dtype='float32',
        callback=callback, finished_callback=event.set)
    with stream:
        timeout = args.blocksize * args.buffersize / f.samplerate
        while data.size != 0:
            data = f.read(args.blocksize, dtype='float32')
            q.put(data, timeout=timeout)
        event.wait()  # Wait until playback is finished
```

Comment: The `play_long_file.py` uses plain Python buffers instead of NumPy arrays, so it is more complicated than you need. With a NumPy array you can just use `outdata[len(data):] = 0`!

Comment: `soundfile.read()` returns a NumPy array and the sampling rate, `soundfile.SoundFile.read()` returns only a NumPy array. Use `soundfile.SoundFile.samplerate` to get the sampling rate.

Comment: @Matthias Thank you very much, now it works great! I'll have to look more in depth into PySoundFile as I should've caught that difference. Appreciate all the effort you've put into building python-sounddevice, and responding to people with questions.